# Fetch locale entries does not work in Live Preview

Tags: live-preview

I need to display booth local and localized entries in the same page.
So I fetch the different localized entries like this :

```
{% set localeEntry = craft.entries.id(myEntry.id).site('default').one() %} {# get the locale data #}
{% set enEntry = craft.entries.id(myEntry.id).site('en').one() %} {# get the english data #}
```

This works perfectly when the page is displaying in the browser, but the variables return empty when the page is displaying in the Craft CP's Live Preview panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resolved here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/5087).
Does not appear on the doc, although.